# Is Unix socket's, sockaddr_un.sun_path case sensitive?

Tags: c, linux, macos, sockets, case-sensitive

struct sockaddr_un serverUNIXAddress;

The following code works under Mac OS 10.9, but not under Linux.  It doesn't die on either, but writing from the client to the server, only works under Mac OS.  I fully understand that it shouldn't work on either.  Why does it work under Mac OS?  Is this a bug in the socket implementation, or just a peculiarity that makes it difficult to port, if the bug is not caught?

client.c

```
//Server domain
serverUNIXAddress.sun_family = AF_UNIX; 

//Server name
strcpy(serverUNIXAddress.sun_path, "rockPaperScissors");
```

server.c

```
strcpy(serverUNIXAddress.sun_path, "RockPaperScissors");
//Create file
bind(serverFd, serverSockAddrPtr, serverLen); 
//Maximum pending connection length
listen (serverFd, 5); 
////[...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Unix domain socket file is created in the file system. The default file system on OS X is case-insensitive. Therefore, the client finds the server's socket using a case-insensitive match.

You can use case-sensitive file systems on OS X. If you did and created your socket file there, then the matching would be case-sensitive, too.

I assume Linux supports case-insensitive file systems. If you used one of those and created your socket file on it, then the matching would be case-insensitive.